# What are the supported Java FX Mouse events on ARM Architecture?

Tags: java, javafx, arm, raspberry-pi, javafx-8

I have compiled a Java FX application on windows platform using e(fx)clipse build

**JDK version on Windows:**

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

I need to deploy the same application on Raspberry Pi. It sports an ARM v6 Architecture.
I am using 2014-12-24-wheezy-raspbian disribution with 256/256MB Memory split.

Java build tested on the platform:

**Default package:**

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

**Java SE Embedded**

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

**Issues Facing:**

1. Java FX runs in Full Screen Mode with blocking all the other displays
2. Mouse.**Drag** events don't work.
3. Dialog, blocks the application.
4. Windows close,minimize options are not visible/disabled

**Solutions tried**

1. Changed the Memory split
   **Result**: Nicer FX Graphics
2. Added dwg_ota.speed=1 (Changes USB bus speed from 480Mb/s to 12Mb/s)
   **Result**: No Change

Is there any way where in I can get **Mouse Drag events** to work? Please do suggest. Where should I report the above bugs regarding Java FX on ARM Platform?

Comment: You can report suspected bugs at the [JavaFX issue tracking site](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).  Note that [Starting with JDK 8u33, JavaFX Embedded is removed from the ARM bundle and is not supported](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-8u33-arm-relnotes-2406696.html).  I am not sure if Oracle will address any issues you file.  It is an open source project, so I guess any open source contributor could provide fixes.  Anyway, I suggest you file relevant bug reports in the issue tracker.  I'm interested to see what happens to them :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate your work on FX. :)